# Store post ID and take it on next page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a page which contain job details. At the bottom there is a button `Apply` which goes to another page with the form for apply.

This is the button on the page

```
<a href="/apply/<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Apply</a>
```

And the url on the next page when is loaded is `/apply/640/` where 640 is the ID of the post (job).

The in the form I've tried to add hidden field which will save the post ID in database and when I retrieve data will know for which job the user is apply.

Tried something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
```

But this obviously saves in the database the ID of the page on which is the form, not the page from which I come.

How can you store the page ID of the job post and pass it as a hidden field in the form? Is it possible also based on the job ID to show the job title above the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your button like

```
<a href="/apply/?job_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Apply</a>
```

And then in the form to `REQUEST` the `ID`

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['job_id']; ?>">
```

( I'm not WordPress expert and I'm not sure if there is better way to be done in WP way. )